# css modules object import returns empty

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am trying to use css modules inside react, but it is not working.

The log of this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../../css/test.css'

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(styles)
        return (
            <div className={styles.app}>
                <p>This text will be blue</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test
```

returns Object {}

and the rendered code are tags with no class:

```
<div><p>This text will be blue</p></div>
```

The css code is available at site, here is my test.css:

```
.test p {
  color: blue;
}
```

If I changed the div to have class='test', the color of p changes to blue

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HappyPack = require('happypack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
var path = require('path')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

function _path(p) {
  return path.join(__dirname, p);
}

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        './assets/js/index'
    ], 

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    devtool: 'inline-eval-cheap-source-map',

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        }),
        new HappyPack({
            id: 'jsx',
            threads: 4,
            loaders: ["babel-loader"]
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css", { allChunks: true })

    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [

             {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css/'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!resolve-url-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]")
            },

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/css/'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]")
            },

            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/js/'),
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loaders: ["happypack/loader?id=jsx"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                query: {
                    name: '/static/img/[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
          'inputmask' : _path('node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask')
        }, 
    }   
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I will update ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your passing the css-loader params to the resolve-url-loader:

```
"css-loader!resolve-url-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
```

Should be:

```
"css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]&importLoaders=1!resolve-url-loader"
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time passed since this question, so my webpack was update many times with another technologies.

This webpack config is working:

```
...
module.exports = {
  entry,
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devtool:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/view/'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.pcss$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/view/'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader:
              'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: function() {
                return [
                  require('postcss-import'),
                  require('postcss-mixins'),
                  require('postcss-cssnext')({
                    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
                  }),
                  require('postcss-nested'),
                  require('postcss-brand-colors')
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|webp)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
  },
  plugins
};
```

I guess that there is an issue with older versions at webpack with this line:

```
'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
```

Try importLoaders and importLoader

You can see my [repo](https://github.com/alexfqc/webpack-react-es6-postcss) too.

Comment: I have this problem in Jest. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292537/imported-styles-object-is-empty-in-jest

Answer (score -2):

In my specific case, I'm using official utility `facebook/create-react-app`. You have to run the following command to get access to the webpack configuration:

```
npm run eject
```

You will then need to edit `config/webpack.config.js` and set the css-loader `modules` option to `true`.

```
use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules:true <-----
              }),
```