# Imported styles object is empty in Jest

Tags: css, reactjs, jestjs, css-modules

I have a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as styles from './RedComponent.css';

class RedComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div className={ styles.red }></div>;
  }
}
```

This is the test case:

```
describe('Test suite', () => {
  test('RedComponent tests', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<RedComponent />);
});
```

`console.log(wrapper.debug());` 
gives

```
<div className={[undefined]}></div>
```

instead of

```
<div className="RedComponent__red"></div>
```

If I console the imported styles I get

```
console.log(styles); // {default: {}}
```

This is only in Jest test cases. Style is not undefined when the app renders in browser.

My jest config:

```
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "./test-setup.js"
  ],
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js}",
    "!**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(md|ttf|txt|eot|ico|otf|svg|png|gif|woff2|woff|jpeg)$": "./file-transformer.js"
  }
}
```

Using jest v21.2.1, identity-obj-proxy v3.0.0 and React v16.0.0.

Comment: try with this `import styles from './RedComponent.css';`

Comment: @MartinShishkov wow that works! Can you post this as an answer? Also do you know why ```import * as``` won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this line

```
import * as styles from './RedComponent.css';
```

to this:

```
import styles from './RedComponent.css';
```

I assume that you are using `css-loader` or similar and this is just how the loader works.

Comment: Yes indeed. In order to enable the CSS modules, you must configure webpack to use the `css-loader` together with the option `modules` set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe worths to check the example: 
https://github.com/keyanzhang/jest-css-modules-example/

I think your `moduleNameMapper` should be like this:

`"^.+\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"`

Comment: Oops I mistook class names that were passed through props for class names applied from imported styles and thought this worked but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `jest/identity-obj-proxy-esm.js` file with the following content:

```js
// This works around the fact we use ES named exports for styles, e.g.:
// import * as styles from './styles.scss'.
// https://github.com/keyanzhang/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8
module.exports = new Proxy(
  {},
  {
    get: function getter(target, key) {
      if (key === '__esModule') {
        // True instead of false to pretend we're an ES module.
        return true;
      }
      return key;
    },
  },
);
```

Edit `jest.config.js`:

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ...
    '\\.(css|scss)$': '<rootDir>/jest/identity-obj-proxy-esm.js',
  }
};
```

João Vieira and https://github.com/keyz/identity-obj-proxy/issues/8#issuecomment-430241345