# webpack: Imported style is an empty object

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

This is my webpack configuration but I am trying to import scss styles that I declared in `:export` block but I get an empty JSON.

Unsurprisingly, there are other people having the same issue:

1. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/206
2. [css modules object import returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092989/css-modules-object-import-returns-empty)

config.webpack.js

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },
        'css-loader',
        'resolve-url-loader',
        'sass-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: [require('autoprefixer')()],
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

I appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: "that I declare in `:export` block" - Can you clarify what you mean? Can you share the exact syntax of your importing and exporting?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `.module.` into your scss file name.

E.g.: `filename.module.scss`

then in your code:

```
import styles from "./filename.module.scss";
```

And you can use the classes of your scss:

```
<div className={styles.yourClassStyle}></div>
```